# Mirror Modifier Clipping Object in Blender 3.0

Tags: mirror-modifier

I was trying to create a sci fi hallway, but I had to mirror everything, specifically, my arches and malls. So I added a Mirror modifier to the arch, then the mirrored arch was clipping through my object, more specifically, rotated 180 degrees and moved to the center of the orgin arch. I have tried flipping the axis, I have tried Changing the merge and enabling clipping, but that has no effect. There is also a Array modifier on top of the mirror modifier because I need the arches in a distanced order, I have tried changing the order of the modifiers but that didn't make a difference. Can anyone help?

I have provided the Blend File in a Dropbox File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lx475l2h05jb64d/Sci%20Fi%20Hallway%202.blend?dl=0

Here are some images too:
[image]

Above Picture is before I add the Mirror Modifier

[image]

Above Picture is After I add the Mirror Modifier

[image]

Above Picture is the Mirror Modifier and the other Array Modifier Settings:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Mirror modifier isn't given a mirror object, then it mirrors around the Object Origin. You can either Snap the origin to the center of the ceiling of the mesh with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, like so :

[image]

Or you can create an empty at the location you want the object to be mirrored, then select the empty as the Mirror Object.

[image]

Comment: Hi Benus! Thanks for your Answer. I didn't know that mirror modifiers used origins, thanks for helping me out!